# Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar Location

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

The `cbar_kws` argument of [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) accepts the parameters that `fig.colobar` accepts.

Is there a way to adjust the placement of the colorbar, simply to adjust the location to the left (especially when the correlation matrix is adjusted to have only a lower triangle). [image]

I can adjust the labels by overriding the tick labels. As of now I still have to adjust the upper-right borders in post-processing, but it would make things much easier if I didn't have to edit the color bar as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar Custom Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035996/seaborn-heatmap-colorbar-custom-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heatmap` accepts a `cbar_ax` argument; if you want to specify the position of the colorbar, the best thing to do is to set up the figure how you want it and then pass the specific axes.

You can also move axes around after plotting through normal matplotlib commands.

Comment: Is it possible to post an example code how to move the colorbar towards left? I have tried without success.