# Seaborn Heatmap Colorbar Custom Location

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

Given this heatmap:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

I want to put the colorbar in a custom location (per axis/plot coordinates) with a custom size.
Specifically, I want it horizontal in the top left corner (outside of the heatmap) with a small (but not yet defined) size. Is this possible? I know there are general location arguments, but those do not allow for what I want to do. I also know I can define a separate colorbar with `plt.colorbar()`, but I am not sure how to customize its location either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ["inset axes"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html) to create an ax for the colorbar that goes perfectly together with the subplot. In [this tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_of_inset_axes.html) "cax" is the "ax" for the colorbar. In seaborn's [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), `cbar_ax` is where the colorbar will be placed (when `cbar_ax` is not given, matplotlib chooses the default position). `cbar_kw` can set additional keywords for the colorbar, such as setting a horizontal orientation.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = inset_axes(ax,
                 width="40%",  # width: 40% of parent_bbox width
                 height="10%",  # height: 10% of parent_bbox height
                 loc='lower left',
                 bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.1, 1, 1),
                 bbox_transform=ax.transAxes,
                 borderpad=0,
                 )
sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cax, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'} )
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8) # make room to fit the colorbar into the figure
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap with custom placed colorbar]

Comment: I should probably update for what I'm seeing but in my actual heatmap, the title is now attached to the color bar and the color bar seems like it needs to be rotated 90 degrees and stretched out the other way. Are these easy fixes? I'm guessing the title is being associated with the wrong axis, though I'm doing plt.title.

Comment: You need `ax.set_title` to set the title.  Are you using the latest seaborn version 0.11.1? Does my example code work in your environment?

Comment: That did it. Sure does. Thanks!